# Android DialogFragment get name of class the dialog was created from

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialogfragment

Within my dialog fragment, I am looking to display the name of the activity from which the dialog fragment was created.

I have tried the following:

```
getActivity().getCallingPackage().getClass().getSimpleName();
```

But this throws a null point exception on getClass().

Any idea of how I could the class name the dialog fragment was created from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DialogFragment, as a Fragment, is always attached to activity. Hence, you do not need to call `getCallingPackage`. Instead, from within your dialog fragment, just call `getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName()`